# is sub-matrices of a pascal matrix non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients

I have a regular n*n symmetric [Pascal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix), I choose a square inside this matrix and I want to know if the sub-matrix is non-singular?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The $i$-th row corresponds to a polynomial $p_i$ of degree $i$, namely $p_i(x)=\binom{x+i}{i}$. The entry in the $j$-th column is the evaluation $p_i(j)$. The polynomials are linearly independent, so the submatrix is the product of a nonsingular matrix with a Vandermonde matrix, and is thus nonsingular.

In fact the determinant of the submatrix is positive; this is a standard application of the [Gessel-Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Gessel-Viennot Lemma, could you elaborate more?

Comment: @SayedMahdi I included a link. The point is that the determinant counts systems of paths in a certain graph and is therefore nonnegative.

Comment: why the polynomials are linearly independent? (AFAIK x and x^2 are dependent. )